# Knockout.js force change after JavaScript changes a textbox

Tags: knockout.js

I have an input:

```
<input id="MyTextBox" type="text" data-bind="value: MyTextBox" />
```

If I change the textbox myself then data binding works... but if I set the text of the textbox with JQuery the textbox changes but no data bind occurs.

```
$("#MyTextBox").val("Some text");
```

How can I change a textbox without any keystrokes and still get binding to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Knockout, you generally shouldn't be using something else to modify the view. So instead of using jQuery to change the textbox value, use Knockout by modifying the observable it's bound to:

```
this.MyTextBox("Some text");
```

If you really need to modify the textbox outside of Knockout, you can signal the `value` binding by generating a change event:

```
$("#MyTextBox").val("Some text").change();
```

Answer (score 1):

When the **change** event was triggered will notify observer see the snippet, but i suggest to you use a ***custom bind handler*** to manipulate the directly DOM with KO;

> *You’re not limited to using the built-in bindings like click, value, and so on — you can create your own ones. This is how to control how observables interact with DOM elements, and gives you a lot of flexibility to encapsulate sophisticated behaviors in an easy-to-reuse way.*
>
> Ref. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

```js
function viewModel(){
     this.val = ko.observable()
};

viewModel.prototype.changeValue= function(){
       $("#txt_data").val("Updated by JQuery: " + $("#txt_jqr").val()).change();      
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
label{
  margin-top:10px;
   display:block;
}
span{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="txt_data">Data-Bind Text:</label>
<input type="text" id="txt_data" data-bind="value: val"/>
<span data-bind="text: val"></span>
<br/>
<label for="txt_jqr">Jquery Text to change:</label>
<input type="text" id="txt_jqr"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button data-bind="click: changeValue">Change view model value</button>
```