# Knockoutjs not saving data if submitted from browser console

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

there is a website developed using knockoutjs,  when I try to fill and submit form using javascript in browser console it submits form but not saves data.

**how to access form: **

Open this link:
[link to open form page](http://studentloans.gov/myDirectLoan/mobile/repayment/repaymentEstimator.action)

Run this in browser console to show **Add loan button**

```
$('.manage_area_login').show();
```

Now click on Add loan button it will show up the form.

And run these three commanda in browser console to fill and submit form.

```
$('#newLoanAmount').val('12');
$('#newLoanInterest').val('2');
$('input[value=Add]').click();
```

After that you will see a Loan will be added with 0 amount
Thats the problem its not saving the field values.

Comment: Do you *develop* that website or do you just want to fill in the form automatically and have otherwise nothing to do with them?

Comment: No I just want to fill form and get calculated value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to manually trigger a change event if manipulate the value like that.

```
$('#newLoanAmount').val('12').trigger('change');
```

Comment: How to trigger a change event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100012/knockout-js-force-change-after-javascript-changes-a-textbox